# Set number of columns in a tablerow dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table-layout and i want to add rows to table dynamically. Number of columns in table will also be decided at runtime and I want to put text-views in each cell on some specified cell. Like if i have three rows and each row will have 15 columns and i want to put a text-view in each column at some index that will be decided at runtime. How can i do that. When i try like this

```
table_row.addView(textview, index, params);
```

It gives me indexout of bound exception. How can I do that. Any kind of help will be appreciated ,

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192109/how-to-add-child-to-tablerow-dynamically-in-android


check this link this will help you to solve your problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use loop for each row and then add the textview to the row.

One simple way to do this is

```
  TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
  TableLayout.LayoutParams tblparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(int i=0; i<row_count;i++)
    {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(Main.this);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(Main.this);
        //you will have to do this for all 15 columns   

        tv1.setLayoutParams(tblparams);
        tv1.setText("Col1data");
        tv2.setLayoutParams(tblparams);
        tv2.setText("Col2data");


        row.addView(tv1);
        row.addView(tv2);

    }
```

I havent tried this but hope it works.